# Fazendo um sistema de rank

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

olá eu estou tentando criar um sistema de Rank usando sqlite3 e Python porem não estou conseguindo  chegar a lugar nenhum,quando eu consulto meu banco de dados ele me retorna isso:
`[('002', 5), ('001', 50), ('003', 80)]` onde 001...002...003 são os id dos usuário e os números depois são os level como eu poderia pegar essa informação e transformar ela para mostrar o  os usuários com maior nível ao menor, uma saída assim:

```
003 80
001 50
002 5
```

Comment: vc precisa de um order by na sua query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira mais simples de resolver seria usando o order by na sua seleção, assim:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Usuario 
 ORDER BY Level DESC
```